# javascript myform.action doesn't

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript in JSP with a form. The form has a dropdownlist with an onchange event to call a function to sumbit the selected value to a servlet. I'm getting an error "Object doesn't support this action". What is the syntax error in my code?

Here is my code:

```
<form id="input" method="post" action="ResultServlet">
<input id=year type=text value="george">
<input id=year type=text value="mary">
<input id=year type=text value="fred">

<select id=casesId onchange = "sendCases();">
<option value="1">Test 1</option>
<option value="2">Test 2</option>
<option value="3">Test 3 </option>
</form>

<script typ=text/javascript>

function sendCases(){
var id = document.forms[0].caseId.options[document.forms[0].caseId.selectedIndex.value;

  if (id !='' || id == null{
   document.forms[0].action('CaseServlet').submit();
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help you could give would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if (id !='' || id == null{
    document.forms[0].action('CaseServlet').submit();
}
```

For:

```
if (id!='' || id == null) {
    document.forms[0].action = 'CaseServlet';
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

1. You have a syntax error where you forget to close the `if`. It might be a typo though.
2. `action` is not a method, it's a property. You don't execute it, you assign a value to it.
3. The `submit()` method only works on the `form` object, not something else :)

Comment: oops, ) left out of if statement... :) Thanks, tried what you suggested and it works.